# How to define the size of List<Map<String, Object>>?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, initialization, size

I am making a method that needs to return a list.

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> mapDO(List<dO> dOList) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> ordersMapList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Object> ordersMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dO.size(); i++) {
            ordersMap.clear();
            ordersMap.put("description", dOList.get(i).getDescription());
            ordersMap.put("size", dOList.get(i).getSize());
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(ordersMap);
            ordersMapList.add(ordersMap);
            System.out.println(ordersMapList);
        }

        return ordersMapList;
    }
```

The problem is: `Arraylist stores the reference and does not copy/create new objects. If you change the stored object reference, it will be reflected in the arrayList as well.`
The output for the above code is:

```
0
{size=One size, description=Product 1}
[{size=One size, description=Product 1}]
1
{size=One size, description=Product 2}
[{size=One size, description=Product 2}, {size=One size, description=Product 2}]
2
{size=One size, description=Product 3}
[{size=One size, description=Product 3}, {size=One size, description=Product 3}, {size=One size, description=Product 3}]
```

I tried to use the .set(index, element) property because to fix this, I need to use setters but I can't seem to find a way to initialize the `oMapList`. I have tried the following but all of them give errors:

1. `List<Map<String, Object>> oMapList = new ArrayList<>(dOList.size());` but this gives sets a capacity and doesn't actually have an effect.
2. `List<Map<String, Object>> oMapList = Arrays.asList(new Map<String, Object>[dOList.size()];` which gives a Generic array creation error.

Is there any other way I can fix this?

Comment: If you need to fix the size of a list, just turn it into an array with `List.asArray()` or `List.asArray(new TypeOfList[0]);`.

Comment: @Schred, when I type `List.`, the only options I see are class, new and try..

Comment: It's an instance method, you need to call it on a list: `ordersMapList.asArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I really understood the question but looking at the code it seems you want a List of Map, but you are adding only one Map to the List which doesn't make sense.

Perhaps what you want is this:

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> mapDO(List<dO> dOList) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> ordersMapList = new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i = 0; i < dO.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, Object> ordersMap = new HashMap<>();
        ordersMap.put("description", dOList.get(i).getDescription());
        ordersMap.put("size", dOList.get(i).getSize());
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(ordersMap);
        ordersMapList.add(ordersMap);
        System.out.println(ordersMapList);
    }

    return ordersMapList;
}
```

Which creates a new map in each iteration, and adds it to the List.